# How can I find a point given another point and a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Given point A = (-1,0,0) and the vector v = (2,-1,1), how could I get a new point (named B) so that the vector formed by A & B (AB) has the same direction and sense of vector v but twice the module of v?

I believe I should start saying that vector B = (x,y,z) so vector AB = (x+1,y,z). I have also calculated the module of v which is Sqrt[6], so the module of the vector AB should be 2*Sqrt[6].

However, I don't know how to continue from here. Any help?

Comment: Welcome. The direction is important. For $(x,y,z)$ to have the same direction and “sense” as $v$, there is a positive number $\lambda$ that $(x,y,z)=\lambda(2,-1,1)$, so $z=\lambda,y=-\lambda=-z,x=2\lambda=2z$. We also know $x^2+y^2+z^2=24$

Comment: What about taking $B=A+2v$?

Comment: Thank you so much,  I have solved the problem. It seems both ways were useful. Thanks a lot!